# como puedo obtener el siguiente archivo json desde una consulta de php - sqlserver

Tags: php, json

Tengo el siguiente query

```
$query="SELECT nombre,edad,genero FROM ...";
$result = sqlsrv_query($_conexion,$query) or die('Error en la consulta');
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
    extract($row);

    $mundos['data'][]=
         array(
                $nombre,
                $edad,
                $genero 
          );

    }

    print_r(json_encode($mundos));
```

sin embargo no aparece nada en la pantalla, si pongo comillas simples en el dato de edad y genero logro que aparezca de la siguiente manera.

```
{"data":[["luis","$edad","$genero"],["maria","$edad","$genero"]
```

.. y asi sucesivamente.

el formato de salida que requiero es el siguiente:

```
{"data":[
    ['luis',"25","hombre"],
    ["maria","30","mujer"],
    ["karla","18","mujer"],
    ["pepe","35","hombre"]


  ]
}
```

Comment: Hola podrias especificar correctamente el formato de salida que deseas porque no es igual en terminos de datos al array que muestras, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

no lo pongas asi:

```
$mundos['data'][]=
     array(
            $nombre,
            $edad,
            $genero 
      );

}
```

creeria yo q con cambiarle aqui es suficiente:

```
$mundos['data'] = array(/*Aqui tus datos*/)
```

y luego un `echo json_encode($mundos);`

Answer (score 0):

Es simple debes aprender un poco mas de arrays asociativos

```
    $mundos['data'][]=
     array(
            'nombre' => $nombre,
            'edad' => $edad,
            'genero' =>$genero 
      );
```